# blueimp detect folder structure

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I'm using the Jquery File Upload of Blueimp.

When I drag&drop a folder structure like this:

```
/img/file1.jpg 
/img/img2/file2.jpg
```

the plugin detects the files included in subfolders, but it keeps a "root" structure in the upload, so my upload it's like:

```
/img/file1.jpg
/img/file2.jpg
```

is there any way to mantain the folder structure of the drag&drop folder?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the path information into the request sent to the server:

```
data.formData = {path: data.files[0].relativePath}
```

And then you'll be able to get it server-side with every other file information, and create the same file structure.

Comment: Thanks,

I could done the upload using this, but, when i reload the page, the uploadHandler.php doesn't list subfolders of the path given for upload, so the plugin doesn't show the recent uploaded files
Is there any way to do that? which method retrive the file list?

Comment: You can save this information client-side (with cookies) or server-side (and getting them when reloading the page)